# kubernetest pod affinity dynamic values in labels

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, affinity

I am looking for an example where I can use dynamic value in `matchExpressions` under `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` in `podAffinity`.

Below is an example of what I want to do:

```
      podAffinity:
        preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - $(user_name)
              topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            weight: 100
```

$(user_name) is a dynamic value that changes on different user that logs in to the system and I either want to pick this dynamic value from an environment value or provide it to the pod at the time of scheduling.

Please provide pointers on how to solve this. thanks

Comment: I wouldn't normally expect users logging into the system to modify Kubernetes API objects at all.  Is something creating this object at run time?  You tagged this question with [tag:kubernetes-helm], is this something you could potentially set in your Helm chart with a deploy-time value?

Comment: Could you describe the use case with more details? What application does and what are you expecting? What do you mean under "user logs in to the system"?

Comment: Sure here is more details on the use case. I have one pod trying to invoke another pod. First pod has the user_name already set as label that needs to be passed on to another pod which it is invoking. On the downstream pod, username should be set in label under pod affinity as described in the question. Also, Yes this will be set in a helm chart.